# SVG CSS3 Show and Hide element on hover from other element

Tags: xml, css, svg, sass

Given the SVG below, I am trying to use CSS to allow one to hover over `tspan.hovertext` classed elements within `g#Main_Layer`, to unhide unrelated `g` elements in `#Hover_Panels`. See below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1280px"
     height="1569.2px" viewBox="0 0 1280 1569.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1280 1569.2;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    text{font-family:'Lato';font-weight:300;}

    #Hover_Text {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .st0{fill:#404041;}
    .st1{font-family:'Lato';font-weight:300;}
    .st5{font-family:'Lato';font-weight:400;}
    .st6{font-size:20px;}
    .st7{fill:none;stroke:#5880AC;stroke-width:1.073;}
    .st22{display:none;}
    .st23{display:inline;fill:#016699;}
    .st24{font-size:26.44px;}

    .hovertext {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .hovertext:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .hovertext:hover + #Hidden_Text {
        display: block;
    }

</style>
<g id="Main_Layer">
    <text id="Hover_Text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1044.0001 878.011)">
        <tspan x="0" y="0" class="st4 st5 st6">hover </tspan>
        <tspan x="0" y="180" class="hovertext st4 st1 st6">HOVER TEXT</tspan>
    </text>
</g>
<g id="Hover_panels">
    <g id="Default_Text" >
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 459.2306 1051.639)">
            <tspan x="0" y="0" class="st16 st1 st19">Default Text </tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
    <g id="Hidden_Text" class="st22">
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 566.0988 1163.5396)" class="st23 st1 st24">Hidden Text</text>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

The problem is I am not exactly in much control of the XML layout (thats generated by Illustrator provided by our designer), and for reasons I wish I could discuss here, we can't use Javascript to accomplish this effect.

How do I get, when using just CSS, when hovering over an .hovertext element, to add `display: block` to the `#Hidden_Text` element, and hide the `#Default_Text` element?

Thank you!

Comment: You won't be able to achieve this with only CSS - you can alter the state of a child element when hovering, not a parent or sibling.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with CSS alone to specify an element not directly behind ("+" Operator) or below (some children).

But you could instead use `visibility: collapse` instead of `display: none` for `#Hidden_Text` (which looks just the same) and define a `<set>` animation in `#Hidden_Text` which sets this property to `visible` if the text is hovered. You need to wrap the hidden text in a `<tspan>` and apply an id to the hovertext to make that possible:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1280px"
     height="1569.2px" viewBox="0 0 1280 1569.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1280 1569.2;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    text{font-family:'Lato';font-weight:300;}

    #Hover_Text {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .st0{fill:#404041;}
    .st1{font-family:'Lato';font-weight:300;}
    .st5{font-family:'Lato';font-weight:400;}
    .st6{font-size:20px;}
    .st7{fill:none;stroke:#5880AC;stroke-width:1.073;}
    .st22{visibility: collapse;}
    .st23{display:inline;fill:#016699;}
    .st24{font-size:26.44px;}

    .hovertext {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .hovertext:hover {
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .hovertext:hover + #Hidden_Text {
        display: block;
    }

</style>
<g id="Main_Layer">
    <text id="Hover_Text" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 1044.0001 878.011)">
        <tspan x="0" y="0" class="st4 st5 st6">hover </tspan>
        <tspan x="0" y="180" id="hovertext" class="hovertext st4 st1 st6">HOVER TEXT</tspan>
   </text>
</g>
<g id="Hover_panels">
    <g id="Default_Text" >
        <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 459.2306 1051.639)">
            <tspan x="0" y="0" class="st16 st1 st19">Default Text </tspan>
        </text>
        <g id="Hidden_Text" class="st22">
            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 566.0988 1163.5396)" class="st23 st1 st24">
                <tspan>Hidden Text</tspan>
                <set attributeName="visibility" to="visible" begin="hovertext.mouseover" end="hovertext.mouseout"/>
            </text>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

I don't know much about what Illustrator allows you to do, but at least it works without JavaScript.